# Why is my function now waiting for password to have a value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, async-await

in index.js

```
 //for the sign-in form request I will use bcrypt
app.post('/auth', async (req, res) => {
   //checks if the userName exists in the database and if it does it gets the hashed password of that account
   let password = await db.userExists(req, res);
   bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, password, function (err, result) {
      if (result == true) {
         console.log('passwords are the same');
         req.session.userid = req.body.userName;
         currentUser = req.body.userName;
         db.getAccountPage(req, res, req.body.userName);
      } else {
         res.render('pages/signIn', {wrongPassword: "Incorrect Password"});
      }
      });
});
```

in db.js

```
const userExists = async (req, res) =>{
    pool.query('Select * from "Users" Where useremail=$1',[req.body.userName],
    (error, results) => {
        if(error)
            return callback(error);
        callback(null, results.rows[0].password);
    });
}
```

I thought await would wait for password db.userExists(req, res); to be returned then password would have a value. When debugging it seems like userExists in db.js is skipped over while the /auth function finishes. I have tried writing the functions many different ways and taking out the awaits in either but every time password is undefined in the /auth function when it reaches the bcrypt password compare. P.S. resutls.rows[0].password when printed does print the hashed password.

Comment: You need to also use await inside userExists, right now your function does not wait, so await pool.query should work, and also don't use a callback ex : `let res = await pool.query()`

Comment: @Lk77: nope, apparently pool.query is called with a callback. Adding await won't work. It's either await without a callback or a callback but wrapped in extra promise resolved manually.

Comment: @WiktorZychla if you don't provide a callback you can use await

Comment: @Lk77: correct. I was under impression that the first version of your comment was missing this detail.

Answer (score 1):

`await` can only be used on promises

Either wrap it in promise

```
const userExists = async (req, res) =>{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject => {
    pool.query('Select * from "Users" Where useremail=$1',[req.body.userName],
    (error, results) => {
        if(error)
            return reject(error);
        resolve(results.rows[0].password);
    });
 })
}
```

Or use promise api

```
const userExists = (req, res) =>{
    return pool.query('Select * from "Users" Where useremail=$1',[req.body.userName])
}
```